# Multiple passes versus a single pass on data for java serial and parallel streams

Tags: java, java-stream

From java doc's java.util.stream package description -

> Stateful operations may need to process the entire input before producing a result. For example, one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream. As a result, under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may need to buffer significant data. Pipelines containing exclusively stateless intermediate operations can be processed in a single pass, whether sequential or parallel, with minimal data buffering.

Can someone explain this sentence? When it speaks about multiple passes v.s. single pass, it is pass on what data? the collection object itself (if one uses the collection object as the stream source)? Why in serial computation, stateful ops can be processed in a single pass?

Answer (score 0):

Some operations over a collection are terminal/terminating (meaning they begin execution and nothing else can be chained to the list of method calls).. some are not.

For method calls that are not terminal, a stream will accumulatively compute the result as it iterates over the stream.

So for something like:

```java
List<String> nameList = List.of("John", "Peter", "Sally", "Barry", "Dilbert", "David", "Drew");
```

you may want to find the first name beginning with `B`. So you could do:

```java
nameList.stream().findFirst((name) -> name.startsWith("B"));
```

And you'd see `Barry` returned... What actually happens is that the stream processes each element one by one, then terminates as soon as the "predicate" (condition) is met... it won't iterate over the elements after "Barry" in the list

`findFirst()` is a terminal method.

A non-terminal operation on a stream would be something like map/filter. You can chain non-terminal operations prior to a terminal one.

```java
List<String> newList = nameList.stream
     .map(name -> return (name.equals("John") ? "Dingbat" : name))
     .filter(name -> name.startsWith("D"))
     .map(name ->  name + " wins")
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This operation would iterate over all elements but starting with the first element "John", map the name to "Dingbat", then filter the resulting value based on whether it starts with "D", if yes, we then map the name from its `value` to `value` +  `wins`.. The result is then collected in the resulting list.

For the next element we get `Peter`, the name isn't `John` so the name is not mapped to `Dingbat` but returned as is ready for the next step - a filter. The name does not begin with "D", so there's nothing further to compute and we can move to the next element. And so on and so forth.

This is my (perhaps basic) understanding of streams.

In terms of operations being stateful or not - stateful operations maintain state across steps. Stateless operations would not retain prior state. Most stream operations you see will be stateless, since maintaining state makes parallel processing more costly as you need to introduce locks to ensure state remains consistent/valid for all operations, otherwise you end up with race conditions/deadlocks and other hard to debug problems.

So for sorting a stream, you'd need to iterate over all elements. You can't do something like `findFirst()` and stop/terminate the search as soon as you find a positive match. The stream needs to sorting all items first, which ends up stored in memory ("buffered"), before the next step(s) in the pipeline [of operations] can be performed. This means you have to process all elements multiple times (mulitple "passes") before you can get the result you're after.

So if you want to take a stream and call .parallel() on it to execute the streams operations in parallel, sort would occur twice in memory, rather than just once (potentially much slower for large datasets).

Essentially the paragraph is telling you to be careful how you use the operations. Stateful operations and a need to process the entire stream first can result in large(r) memory requirements, which may exhaust memory leading to runtime exceptions - bad/avoid.